# Php Sendgrid issue on server

Tags: php, smtp, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email using sendgrid but i got authentication error on server but working on localhost and staging server any idea I am stuck. I used `host = "smtp.sendgrid.net"`

```php
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              
    try {
        $content = file_get_contents('email.php');
        $mail->isSMTP(); // using SMTP protocol                                     
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'; // SMTP host as gmail 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = 'true';  // enable smtp authentication                             
        $mail->Username = 'apikey';  // sender gmail host              
        $mail->Password = 'SG.*************************';                       
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  // for encrypted connection                           
        $mail->Port = '587';   // port for SMTP   
        // $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;  
        $mail->IsHTML(true); 
        $mail->setFrom('noreply@****.com', "Test"); // sender's email and name
        $mail->addAddress($email, "Receiver");  // receiver's email and name
        $mail->Subject = 'Welcome to Test';
        $mail->Body    = $content;
        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) { // handle error.
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully debug the situation with such limited information. If you received an authentication error, and you're using SendGrid, then I recommend you use the SendGrid dashboard to start debugging the issue. Specifically, look in the [blocks](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/blocks), [bounces](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/bounces), and [invalid](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/invalid_emails) sub-sections of the **[Suppressions](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/invalid_emails)** tab.

They should give you much more detailed information about why an email was not accepted to be sent, or could not be sent, including links to the relevant documentation. I hope this helps.